# Arena: How to have the engine only analyze and let me play as both White and Black

Tags: engines, arena

I enjoy watching chess videos where, say, an opening is analyzed and besides the main line, the lecturer also explores alternatives and explains why they are bad or good. I would like to do this exploration on my own.

The way I imagine doing it is playing as both White and Black on my Arena 3.5 with Stockfish engine installed. I'd like ot be doing all the moves myself, but having the engine explore possible moves only as suggestions.

For now, I am stuck having to stop the engine on every move by pressing the red cross on the rightside panel, undoing the move done after I press the cross, and performing my own move. How to set up Arena to work the way I would like, or perhaps there is alternative free software that does this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Arena 3.5, you can hit the "Edit" button next to "Analyze", and continue doing moves. In the edit mode, it does not try to do a move automatically. If you keep the "Analyze" button as pressed, then it will analyze both sides of the game. I think this is what you are looking for. See screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: Yes! It seems that both options - _Edit_ and _Analyze_ need to be enabled for the behavior I want, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Fritz version something like 5.32 is available as a free download. Fritz allows you to plug in your engine of choice, so no problem using the Fritz interface with the latest free engine. Stockfish is fine and works on my setup with Fritz.

Once you do that Fritz has an infinite analysis mode which does exactly what you want.

Edit: Fritz 5.32 looks to be difficult to find. However ChessDB (http://chessdb.sourceforge.net/) will also do this. Just attach the engine of your choice and open an analysis window as you enter the moves on the board the analysis will show up in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Keshav's solution works. But I tend to set the engine in infinite mode (Levels > Infinite), and it never makes a move and also lets you input moves.

Answer (score 0):

I think the free but excellent LucasChess software that is geared more toward tutoring may be a better option. ArenaChess is a great app with much flexibility but gives little attention to helping one to learn the game: it does not even include a hints option.